# Not able to connect to Influxdb running in docker container

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu-18.04, influxdb

I am trying to setup InfluxDB database for my project and I added InfluxDB container in my Docker but when I try to connect to the database using the command `influx` it always shows following message

```
root@0e36c4d4a53f:/# influx

Influx Client

Usage:
  influx [command]

Available Commands:xxxxxxx

Flags:
  -h, --help   Help for the influx command

Use "influx [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

I am supposed to get

```
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.7.7
InfluxDB shell version: 1.7.7".
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: are you using official influxdb container ?, whats the command you are using to run container ? and from where are you trying to access the db?

Comment: Hi @Savio Mathew, I used following command to install InfluxDB 2.0 via putty <$sudo docker run --name=influxdb -d -p 8086:8086 influxdb> Then following commands to go into influxDB <$ sudo docker exec -it influxdb /bin/bash> <root@86a2946cfa9c:/# influx.>

Comment: We have tested in our local environment ,By creating two docker influxdb containers  with different image versions(2.0 & 1.8). 

The container that is running with influxdb version 1.8 post running the below cmdlets we are able to get the connection urls & list of databases 
###
    docker exec -it influxdb /bin/bash
    influx ( #share you the connecting url)
    show databases (#list the all databases)
###

Comment: The container that is running with influxdb version 2.0 post running the below cmdlets to  list the connecting URL 
###
    docker exec -it influxdb /bin/bash
    influx config (# will give you the connection url)
###
you can the refer output screen shot [https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIICw.png]
Here is the reference documentation to work with [influxdb v2.0](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, enter the container and run this command:

```
influx v1 shell --org-id {org-id} --token {token}
```

{org-id} is from:

1. open http://localhost:8086/
2. open menu profile > about > Organization ID

{token} is from:

1. http://localhost:8086/api/v2/authorizations